# DataGridViewColumn - setting ReadOnly throws "Index Was Out of Range" in one strange case

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've got a bug that's driving me crazy. I have some generic code that I use to manage my (WinForms) application's `DataGridView` columns. Setting the column header text, width, display index, that sort of thing.

I had a user report a bug when loading one particular screen. At first, I couldn't even reproduce it, but I finally figured out that it was happening (a) when one particular column was visible, and (b) when there were exactly two rows of data(!). One row of data, it works fine. More than two rows of data, it works fine. Two rows of data, it fails.

The `DataGridView` is bound to a `DataTable`.

This is the code that is failing:

```
private static void ApplyColumnReadOnly(DataGridViewColumn dgvc, IColumn ci) {
    if (dgvc != null && ci != null) {
        dgvc.ReadOnly = ci.IsReadOnly;
    }
}
```

`IColumn` is an interface that I use to store all the column metadata (column header, whether it's visible, display index, readonly, etc.). I have checked to verify that the `IsReadOnly` property is set correctly (presumably it would throw a different error if it weren't).

The column in question is a `boolean` column that displays in the `DataGridView` as a checkbox.

Here is the error I get:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.SharedRow(Int32 rowIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetReadOnlyCellCore(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean readOnly)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.RemoveIndividualReadOnlyCellsInColumn(Int32 columnIndex)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetReadOnlyColumnCore(Int32 columnIndex, Boolean readOnly)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBand.set_ReadOnly(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn.set_ReadOnly(Boolean value)
   at Ipreo.Orion.Common.DataGridManager.ApplyColumnReadOnly(DataGridViewColumn dgvc, IColumn ci)
```

So, the workaround I've discovered is to manually step through all the rows in the `DataGridView` and set the column's `ReadOnly` attribute manually, which seems to be what's happening in the stack trace above, but I'm afraid that this might not scale well.

As I mentioned, it only happens when I have exactly two rows of data to display, and it only happens with one boolean column.

I've searched extensively on the error and pretty much every method call from the stack trace, but as far as I can tell, I seem to be the first person to ever report such an error.

Any advice or pointers on how to proceed (either by fixing the bug or additional debugging tools) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code(e.g. in github), and let me debug.

Comment: Sadly no. The code is proprietary. I can add some more context if it would help, but I'm baffled by the fact that the error is occurring seven layers deeper than any code that I wrote. It seems to be failing while iterating through the rows, whereas my code doesn't explicitly reference rows at all.

Comment: You can use simpler **demo** instead, with no proprietary.

Comment: Technically speaking, it's all proprietary, but I'll see if I can recreate the bug in a simple example.

Comment: That will be best, and during creating such demo, maybe you will find some essential root cause yourself.

Comment: I had the same problem. Used the same work around.